# I'm trying to add a ProgressBar in a JetpackCompose project and I'm getting a bug

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a Circular Progress Bar in my project but I am getting a weird bug when I add the requested @ExperimentalComposeUiApi.
I have a function that is called once when the fragment launches but when I add the @ExperimentalComposeUiApi it seems to be called without stop. It keeps calling the functions and the progress bar appears blinking all the time.
Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Like this works fine without the progress bar

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: MovieViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                val loading = viewModel.loading.value

                val args: DetailFragmentArgs by navArgs()
                val movieDetailFromNetwork = viewModel.movieDetails.value
                val savedMovie = viewModel.savedMovie.value
                viewModel.onTriggerEvent(MovieEvent.GetSavedMovieEvent(args.imdbId))
                viewModel.onTriggerEvent(MovieEvent.GetMovieDetailsEvent(args.imdbId))
```

with the progress bar I'm getting the error

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: MovieViewModel by viewModels()


    @ExperimentalComposeUiApi
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                val loading = viewModel.loading.value

                val args: DetailFragmentArgs by navArgs()
                val movieDetailFromNetwork = viewModel.movieDetails.value
                val savedMovie = viewModel.savedMovie.value
                viewModel.onTriggerEvent(MovieEvent.GetSavedMovieEvent(args.imdbId))
                viewModel.onTriggerEvent(MovieEvent.GetMovieDetailsEvent(args.imdbId))
//                NewMoviesTheme(displayProgressBar = loading) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "testest")
                    Scaffold(
                        topBar = {
                            TopAppBar(
                                title = {
                                    Text(text = args.title)
                                },
                                navigationIcon = {
                                    IconButton(onClick = {
                                        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_detailFragment_to_movieListFragment)
                                    }) {
                                        Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = null)
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    ) {
                        Box{
                            CircularIndeterminateProgressBar(isDisplayed = loading, 0.3f)
```

below is the log with the function being called over and over

```
2021-05-22 17:20:58.313 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.314 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.401 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.401 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.425 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.425 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.468 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.468 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.522 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.523 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.572 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.572 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.607 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.610 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.658 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.658 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.689 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
2021-05-22 17:20:58.689 9458-9458/com.example.newmovies D/debugTag: launchJob: finally called.
```

Comment: What is the value being passed to `isDisplayed`? Please share the `ViewModel` code.

Comment: Your issue is not clear. In any case you should use `val loading = viewModel.loading.value.observeAsState()`